# Visual Studio 2008 SP1 Not allowing to add website datasources

Tags: visual-studio-2008, dataset, reporting, datasource

I have a project with two reports (master.rdlc & detail.rdlc) which both uses datasets to fill data. So far so good. They work ok, or used to work ok. For some reason, they lost the references to the datasets and the datasets are not showing in the Website Data Sources window so I'm unable to work with them.

Also, in the window Website Data Sources all the buttons but the "Refresh" one are disabled.

What can be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Same issue - except I haven't even got a report running yet, stuck with an empty document and no way to add datasources.

Getting a very strange message when I go to the Report>Datasources menu item, that it can't load the ajaxtoolkit assembly... ?!

*** Update *****
Set my target framework from 3.5 to 3.0 - seems to be working now

Answer (score 1):

Try

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yft2c9ad.aspx

On the menu bar, choose View, Other Windows, Data Sources (or choose the Shift+Alt+D keys).